# Vegalite= Interactive line: data selector

Tags: charts, vega-lite

I'm trying to add a slider that allows you to change the range of dates (see chart screenshot). [image: chart example]

Original code of the basic graph:

```
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v5.json",
  "title": {
    "text": "Share of Total Net Worth Held by the Top 1%",
    "subtitle": "Source: Board of Governors of the Federal Reserve System (US)",
    "subtitleFontStyle": "italic",
    "subtitleFontSize": 10,
    "anchor": "start",
    "color": "black"
  },
  "data": {
    "url": "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jamieprince/jamieprince.github.io/main/data_FRED-WFRBST01134.json",
    "format": {"type": "json", "property": "observations"}
  },
  "height": 300,
  "width": 310,
  "mark": "line",
  "encoding": {
    "x": {
      "field": "date",
      "type": "temporal",
      "title": null,
      "axis": {"grid": false}
    },
    "y": {
      "field": "value",
      "type": "quantitative",
      "title": null,
      "axis": {"grid": true}
    }
  }
}
```

I am basing it on another chart I found but I can't seem to get it to work

Code of chart I'm trying to emulate:

```
{
    "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v5.json",


    "title": {
    "text": "Inflation - since 1800",
    "subtitle": "RPI: long series: annual percentage change ",
    "subtitleFontStyle":"italic",
    "subtitleFontSize":10,
    "anchor": "start",
    "color": "black"
  },


    "width":300,
    "height":300,

    "data": {
        "name":"myData",
        "url": "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/RDeconomist/RDeconomist.github.io/main/charts/ONSinflation/data_MM23-CDSI.json",
        "format": {
          "type":"json",
          "property": "years"
        }},
  

    "mark":{
      "type": "line",
      "color":"#00BFFF",
      "strokeWidth":2,
      "opacity":1
    },

    "transform": [
      {"filter": "datum.year>minYear"},
      {"filter": "datum.year<maxYear"}
    ],

    "params": [    
      {"name":"minYear", "value":1800,
         "bind":{
           "input": "range",
           "min": 1800, 
           "max": 2021, 
           "step": 1,
           "name": "Start year:"}
      },

      {"name":"maxYear", "value":2021,
         "bind":{
           "input": "range",
           "min": 1800, 
           "max": 2021, 
           "step": 1,
           "name": "End year:"}
      }
    ],


    "encoding": {
      
      "x": {
        "field": "date",
        "type": "temporal",
        "title":null
        },
  
      "y": {
        "field": "value",                
        "type": "quantitative",
        "title":null,
        "scale":{
          "domain":{
            "data": "myData", 
            "field": "value"}}
        }
  }
}
```

I managed to get Vega to create another column that has just the years but for some reason, the data just still isn't appearing

Code that gives what's shown in the screenshot

```
{
 "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega/v5.json",
 "autosize": {"type": "fit-x", "contains": "padding"},
 "background": "#FFFFFF",
 "padding": 5,
 "height": 310,
 "title": {
   "text": "Share of Total Net Worth Held by the Top 1%",
   "subtitle": "Source: Board of Governors of the Federal Reserve System (US)",
   "subtitleFontStyle": "italic",
   "subtitleFontSize": 10,
   "anchor": "start",
   "color": "black",
   "subtitleColor": "black"
 },
 "style": "cell",
 
 "data": [
   {
   "name":"myData",
   "url": "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jamieprince/jamieprince.github.io/main/data_FRED-WFRBST01134.json",
   "format": {"type": "json", "property": "observations"},
     
     "transform": [
       {"type": "formula", "expr": "year(datum.date)", "as": "year"},
       {"type": "filter", "expr": "datum.year>=minYear"},
       {"type": "filter", "expr": "datum.year<=maxYear"}
     ]
   }
 ],
 "signals": [
   {
     "name": "width",
     "init": "isFinite(containerSize()[0]) ? containerSize()[0] : 200",
     "on": [
       {
         "update": "isFinite(containerSize()[0]) ? containerSize()[0] : 200",
         "events": "window:resize"
       }
     ]
   },
   {
     "name": "minYear",
     "value": 1989,
     "bind": {
       "input": "range",
       "min": 1989,
       "max": 2021,
       "step": 1,
       "name": "Start year: "
     }
   },
   {
     "name": "maxYear",
     "value": 2021,
     "bind": {
       "input": "range",
       "min": 1989,
       "max": 2021,
       "step": 1,
       "name": "End year: "
     }
   }
 ],

 "mark": "line",
 "encoding": {
   "x": {
     "field": "year",
     "type": "temporal",
     "title": null,
     "axis": {"grid": false}
   },
   "y": {
     "field": "value",
     "type": "quantitative",
     "title": null,
     "axis": {"grid": true},
     "scale":{
         "domain":{
           "data": "myData", 
           "field": "value"}}
   }
 }
}
```

[image: Chart not showing data]

I could really use some help, have spent hours trying to figure it out. I would be eternally grateful

Comment: Do you want your  chart config in vega or vega-lite ? Because half your config is part of vega and another half iseems from vega-lite

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There seems to be some configuration issue as the signal from vega and params from vega-lite was mixed. I have made your configuration same as the one working with slider params.

Below is the Config or refer [editor](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega-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-DwmgCMaFwSMoMiAB5kAsWicN8ABdJQ3G9BBMJAs0LStKjZF4polDnQQGC5ABOAAOZSAkcGJ10cHBVBcb1ZDIPdrUcNBCjUjSVysR9igfQoL3jcylHNS1ensNYhjI14lwUUBXKkpAeLo6wFKUtAHzshyQCYLTTV0-T0EM4zrGk8zLKUbiIqixycGciS3PQctoi8uifN8ASlDDWwvCM00bMY7ZtOI40TM3K0sQQHBVjhZoyTQWRIMEHkLBoTDQHCSo0BMOFkQqpQP0anYXDCtrBxcABHBheVuedSD6u5jEGwRhuUUbxpASbtMvJTl2gOF2mIth83kdcixQdAbXtE0uzjZb0FWpcKt8IA):

```
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v5.json",
  "autosize": {"type": "fit-x", "contains": "padding"},
  "background": "#FFFFFF",
  "padding": 5,
  "height": 310,
  "width": "container",
  "title": {
    "text": "Share of Total Net Worth Held by the Top 1%",
    "subtitle": "Source: Board of Governors of the Federal Reserve System (US)",
    "subtitleFontStyle": "italic",
    "subtitleFontSize": 10,
    "anchor": "start",
    "color": "black",
    "subtitleColor": "black"
  },
  "style": "cell",
  "data": {
    "name": "myData",
    "url": "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jamieprince/jamieprince.github.io/main/data_FRED-WFRBST01134.json",
    "format": {"type": "json", "property": "observations"}
  },
  "mark": {"type": "line", "color": "#00BFFF", "strokeWidth": 2, "opacity": 1},
  "transform": [
    {"calculate": "year(datum.date)", "as": "year"},
    {"filter": "datum.year>minYear"},
    {"filter": "datum.year<maxYear"}
  ],
  "params": [
    {
      "name": "minYear",
      "value": 1989,
      "bind": {
        "input": "range",
        "min": 1989,
        "max": 2021,
        "step": 1,
        "name": "Start year: "
      }
    },
    {
      "name": "maxYear",
      "value": 2021,
      "bind": {
        "input": "range",
        "min": 1989,
        "max": 2021,
        "step": 1,
        "name": "End year: "
      }
    }
  ],
  "encoding": {
    "x": {
      "field": "date",
      "type": "temporal",
      "title": null,
      "axis": {"grid": false}
    },
    "y": {
      "field": "value",
      "type": "quantitative",
      "title": null,
      "axis": {"grid": true},
      "scale": {"domain": {"data": "myData", "field": "value"}}
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: You're an absolute lifesaver! Thank SO you!